# how to compare range of values in tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have one tensor,

```
tensor([[ 0.2213, -0.1180,  1.1186],
        [-0.9943, -0.7679, -1.7057]])
```

Now I want to assign value to each element according to condition, something like this:

```
torch.where(x < 0, 0, x)
torch.where(0 <= x <= 1, 5, x)
torch.where(2 <= x <= 3, 7, x)
```

ofcourse, 'where' does not accept such conditions. How can I achieve it? torch.isin also does not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is valid since `x < 0` produces a boolean tensor.

When multiple clauses are needed you can use boolean operators such as [`torch.logical_and`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.logical_and.html):

```
>>> torch.where(torch.logical_and(0 <= x, x <= 1), 5, x)
```

Notice that for two given boolean tensors: `a` and `b`, `torch.logical_and(a, b)` will be equivalent to `a*b`, since `*` is the `AND` operator for booleans.

```
>>> torch.where((0 <= x)*(x <= 1), 5, x)
tensor([[ 5.0000, -0.1180,  1.1186],
        [-0.9943, -0.7679, -1.7057]])

>>> torch.where((2 <= x)*(x <= 3), 7, x)
tensor([[ 0.2213, -0.1180,  1.1186],
        [-0.9943, -0.7679, -1.7057]])
```